# How to install OSX developer tools without a monitor?

Tags: python, macos

I can use ssh to access the OSX machine, but I cannot touch it, no desktop and no VNC.

when I use pip install gevent, it raised an error said

```
xcode-select: error: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', and no install could be requested (perhaps no UI is present), please install manually from 'developer.apple.com'.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I want to know if there is anyway can install OSX developer tools using ssh.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107307/how-can-i-install-the-command-line-tools-completely-from-the-command-line ?

Answer (score 4):

You can get Command Line Tools directly from developer page.
       http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_8.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_8.1.dmg

Then

```
sudo hdiutil attach Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_8.1.dmg
sudo installer -package /Volumes/<mount_point>/<installer>.pkg -target /
sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/<mount_point>
```